# Error while trying to parse date

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using itextsharp to extract the modified date from a pdf file.  The string gets returned in this format: `D:20120224093340`.  I'm trying to parse that string into a date time like so:

```
string modDate = "";

reader.Info.TryGetValue("ModDate", out modDate);

System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

pdfModDate = DateTime.ParseExact(formattedDate, "D:yyyyddMMHHmmss", provider);
```

But I get this error message: The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

I have no idea what this error means.  This code should be working...

Comment: your not doing anything with modDate

Comment: Try to parse the date "manually" with your conditions. You'll get the 2nd day of the 24th month of 2012. This should help you understand what the error means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your month is 24, which is not supported by the Gregorian calendar :-)

```
D:20120224093340
D:yyyyddMMHHmmss
        ^^
```

Comment: Wow don't know how I overlooked that.  Thanks!

Comment: @broke: Time for a coffee break :D

Answer (score 3):

Try `"D:yyyyMMddHHmmss"`. You got day and month switched.

Answer (score 2):

The date you provided is in the following format:

```
D:yyyyMMddHHmmss
```

Not the english format MM/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 1):

You could try stripping off the D: from the beginning of the string. The ParseExact function recognizes capital D as a special character in the date format string. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) "D" is short for long date format.

Also, you need to switch day and month. The order they are returning it in is Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second.

Answer (score 1):

```
    string date = "D:20120224093340";
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(date,"D:yyyyMMddHHmmss",provider);
```

After switching ddMM.